# jquery $.ajax function using a variable URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var array = new Array();
$.get('comics.txt', function(data) {
    array = data.split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var $page = array[i];
        $.ajax({
            url: $page,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

comics.txt is a file which contains some urls, separated by commas.

In the above code, the $.ajax call does not work; $page is the correct url, but it's not working in the context.  alert(data) causes a blank alert box to come up.  I need help figuring out a way to get the data from each page in the array called array.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: It looks like your for loop is executing faster than your ajax can fetch data, or data mismatch may be occurring between loops, hence the blank alerts.

Comment: also ajax has the same-domain requirement. you can't fetch if your url is from a different domain.

Comment: If so, how can I get data via javascript from foreign URLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is `$page` a url on your domain?... if not, you cannot do ajax...

## [same domain policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

---

> If so, how can I get data via javascript from foreign URLs?

you have yo get it from your server...

for example..

```
var array = new Array();
$.get('comics.txt', function(data) {
    array = data.split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var $page = array[i];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your/server/url.php?page=' + $page,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

`your/server/url.php` can get the page for you...

Comment: Thanks! Is there a javascript way to retrieve foreign URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make requests to other domains from your client's browser.  It's a huge security risk.  This code will work if the URLs in the text file are on the same domain as the javascript is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross-site script by dynamically adding a script element to the DOM with the src attribute pointing to wherever you like; as long as whatever's referenced in src returns JavaScript (protip: execute a pre-defined function at the end of the XSS for AJAX-like behaviour), it should work.

Site 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('body').append($("<script>").attr('src', "http://mydomain.com/xss.js"));
} );

function alerty (thing) {
    alert(thing);
}
</script>
```

Site 2 (xss.js):

```
var mystring = "hello";

if (typeof(alerty) != "undefined") {
   alerty(mystring);
}
```

Obviously the URL doesn't have to be a flat file - it could be JavaScript which is constructed by PHP based on GET requests in the URL. Also this presumes you have control of the remote data, which you may not.