# Ajax request not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is driving me insane. I have this code on a site I'm developing:
http://jsfiddle.net/agNQt/

In firebug on jsfiddle it fires the ajax but obviously the path can't be found.

On my development it doesn't show anything in firebug, if I change the path so it doesn't exist I get this error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
> /includes/ajax1.php"

Usually it will show the post request and return the output. But I get nothing.

Any suggestions what it could be before I go crazy?

Thanks.

-EDIT-

Anthony Grist seems to be the closest. I changed it to the full path now it sends the request and returns the value. It was working without the full path yesterday! Crazy. Any suggestions why? Surely it's not good using the full path?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a htaccess blocking access to that file?

Comment: are you sure the paths are correct? how's your ajax1.php, can you post it?

Comment: have you tried `http://www.mydomain.com/includes/ajax1.php` or `./includes/ajax1.php` instead of `/includes/ajax1.php`?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the question as well, please? jsFiddles are great, and to be encouraged, but they aren't supposed to be a replacement for including all the necessary information in the question itself. If that link expires, or jsFiddle is down, the question becomes useless.

Comment: depending on the browser you might need to add into the ajax this         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

Comment: Anthony seems to closest. I changed the path to the full URL and it seems to be working again. I had this working without the full URL yesterday, now it suddenly stopped working! Crazy. Any suggestions why i need the full URL path?

Comment: In your JS: `url: "includes/ajax.php",`, change it to `url: "/includes/ajax.php",`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either ClydeFrog. :(

Comment: Well, what path is the script in and what path is the PHP file in? If the script is in `/js/script.js`, it'll try to fetch `/js/includes/ajax.php` if you use a relative path.

Comment: I think you might have the same problem as [this guy, and with a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315466/jquery-ajax-function-using-a-variable-url)

Comment: I've tried the relative path too. its only working if I have the full URL in :(

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked what the paths are. If the relative path doesn't work you have the path wrong.

Comment: it's in '/mysite/includes/ajax.php' and the script is in the root.

Comment: It was working yesterday with 'includes/ajax.php', but some crazy reason it's not today

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain your domain in your JS like this and then use it with ajax:

[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3L3w/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#typedrop").live('change', function() {
      var output = $(this).val();
      var querystring = "option=" + output;
      var mysite = document.domain;
         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: querystring,
                    url: mysite + "/includes/ajax.php",
                    success: function(){

                    }

         });
         return false;        
    });


});     ​
```